# Datetime can't take year below 1000

Tags: python, datetime

For example print(days_diff((1000, 1, 1), (9999, 12, 31))) - works fine, but print(days_diff((100, 1, 1), (9999, 12, 31))) - says that - "time data '(100, 1, 1)' does not match format '(%Y, %m, %d)'". How to solve it?

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def days_diff(d1, d2):

    d1 = dt.strptime(str(d1), "(%Y, %m, %d)")
    d2 = dt.strptime(str(d2), "(%Y, %m, %d)")

    return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is turning the tuple into a str and then parsing that into a datetime. But you can also pass your `(year, month, day)` tuple directly to the datetime constructor:

````py
from datetime import datetime as dt

def days_diff(d1, d2):

    d1 = dt(*d1)
    d2 = dt(*d2)

    return abs((d2 - d1).days)

# result: 3615899
print( days_diff((100,1,1), (9999,12,31)) )```
````

Answer (score 1):

`%Y` denotes a year in [`yyyy`-format](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/). When providing a three-digit-number, that criterion is not met. You'll need to pad your year with leading zeroes to make it match the format, e.g. `dt.strptime('(0999, 12, 12)', "(%Y, %m, %d)")` will convert to a valid datetime no problem. **EDIT**: for a better way to do the conversion see xjcl's answer. Leaving this up to explain the error